# jquery mask clean values on invalid

Tags: jquery, html, validation, mask, jquery-mask

How can I make to jQuery accepts a wrong value in a field with a mask.

For the code bellow:

```
$("#element").mask("999.999.999-99");
```

If I put the value 444.444.44 on the field, on focus out the value will be cleaned.

There is a way to doesn't changes this value?

Comment: What's the point in using a mask on the input anyway if you want to accept wrong input?

Comment: The point is that I want to accepts only numbers and if the users fogert one number, the wrong value SHOULD stay on the screen. Do you know the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer!

Just add "?" before the mask:

```
$('#element').mask('?999.999.999-99');
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to approach this is using the autoclear option:

```
$("#element").mask("999.999.999-99", {autoclear: false});
```